# c#: Exit Powershell cmdlet programmatically

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm writing an Powershell-cmdlet in c#, that should behave like this:

```
if(RequirementsDoNotMeet)
{
   ExitCmdletAndReturnToPowershellCommandline()
}
```

How can I make this kind of "Cmdlet.Exit" work?

piccus

Comment: [`Cmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.automation.cmdlet.throwterminatingerror.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

try use simply instruction

```
  return
```

Comment: Thx. I did some modification to make return solve tzhe problem.

Comment: Happy then. Set my response like a possible solution then :)